# Wait for Linux Mint 13 or install Linux Mint Debian version?

Tags: linux-mint, distributions, gnome3

I have been using Linux Mint 12 with Gnome 3 and I'm very happy with it except about the fact that it get very slow software updates, hoping that Linux Mint 13 will have Gnome 3.4 and Linux kernel 3.2 shall wait for it?
Or shall I install Debian based Linux Mint which gets rolling updates?
What would be a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't afford to live with the risks of a rolling release distro (sometimes things will break and updates won't be smooth - this from my experience with Arch), wait for Mint 13.

Otherwise, the Debian-based Mint should be OK.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion.